# Как удалить теги span, но оставить их содержимое?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как удалить теги span, но оставить их содержимое на всей странице.

Пример:

```
<div> Пример <span style="color:red;"> стро<span style="color:green;">ки</span></span></div>
```

После преобразования должно быть так:

```
<div> Пример  строки</div>
```

Comment: Забыл написать это нужно сделать на стороне клиента средствами JavaScript.

Comment:     $('div').text($(div).text())

это простейшее и не идеальное решение вашей задачи, но для вашего примера должно работать на ура

Comment: Немного не то.
А если вместо <div>, будут <p> или другие элементы.

Comment: Тогда ищи в тех, которые нужно заменить тэги.  
Можешь вообще по классу искать (`$('.myClass')`), тогда от типа ноды ничего не зависит.

Comment: @Wapo тогда лови полный ответ http://hashcode.ru/questions/409008#409024

Comment: @Wapo, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор, если нужно, укажите более определенно:

```
$('div span').replaceWith(function(){
     return $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Юзай метод `jQueryElement.text()`. [Мана.](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Работа_с_текстовым_содержимым_элемента)
Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/a6pbpr29/1/

Comment: @TheDoctor, пример порадовал ;) Поправьте, а то могут и не понять.

Comment: @Deonis, поправил, что-то не так поставилось :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div span').each(function(){
    var span = $(this);
    span.after(span.text()).remove();
});
```